# relative positioning with percentage values in top property

Tags: css, layout, html, css-position

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsf5B/2/)

The above snippet renders the way I intend it in Chrome (v.20).
However in Firefox 11 and IE 9 the 2nd and 3rd content divs do not appear to take into account top and left CSS values.

What is the correct method of relative positioning with percentage widths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  your case container doesn't have height. You can use this:

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```