# Move a DIV vertically by -100% of its height

Tags: html, css

I want to move a DIV vertically by -100% of its height.

- % values doesn't work.
- The height of the image is set to `100vh`. So I know I can just do `top: -100vh`, but I'm trying to understand why the code below doesn't work.
- I tried with `margin-top: -100%` but it's not positioned correctly. [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG9kj.jpg) how it's rendered on my browser (`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36`).
- `absolute` positioning is not allowed on my case.
- While a (now deleted) answer resolved it using `transform`, I'm interested in a less experimental approach. [MDN warns about](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform) using `transform`.

In the snippet, I'm trying to place `div2` behind (or above, doesn't matter) `div1`. I tried with `relative` and `top: -100%`, but isn't working.

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: When I added `margin-top: -100%` to `div2`, it did infact go behind `div1`, which if I'm understanding correctly, is okay? As for why `top` doesn't work: The container element would need to have a fixed height for this to be a viable option.

Comment: It goes way more than its set height (100vh), as seen here http://i.imgur.com/WTXS7uF.png, Even if the source images are the same size (which they are not in the example), the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11777470), I came to the conclusion that I need to set the `height` of the `html` and `body` elements.

Updated snippet without scrollbars and padding.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: -100%;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The percentage value is relative to the size of the container which is the size of `body` tag. You can set `html, body { height: 100%; }` to make it work.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Or, use negative margin `margin-top: -100vh;`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
  margin-top: -100vh;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Or, use `vh` of `top: -100vh;` rather than percentage.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* hide empty space caused by offset */
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -100vh;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Or, use `transform: translateY(-100vh);`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* hide empty space caused by offset */
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-100vh);
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

You can also set both divs to `position: absolute;` with full page width and height, by default div2 has higher stacking order as it renders later in the DOM, or use `z-index` to adjust that.

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.div1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

margin-top: -100%; seems to work:

```css
.div1, .div2 {
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.div1 {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/cats/");
}

.div2 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100vh;
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/food/");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <div class="div1"></div>
 <div class="div2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know why it does not accept

> top: -100%;

as it accepts

> top: -100px;

so it can have negative value, may be it just doesnt accept percentages.. I am over asked here :P.

Hope i helped a little bit.

Comment: Doesn't work. See how it goes way above it's height: http://i.imgur.com/WTXS7uF.png

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with `margin-top: -100%` but it's not positioned correctly.

I don't know did you say that, as it works in my case.

but strange thing here is that why this code, i mean your original code doesn't work here as it is working absolutely fine on [liveweave.com](http://liveweave.com/) ... but yet it doesn't work with other tools.

**UPDATE 1**

try `margin-top: -100vh;` it works perfectly fine on every browser and each viewport.

while `margin-top: -100%` only works if your viewport is full screen (in my case, if i changed viewport it didn't work).

Comment: with `margin-top: -100%` it works: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/hihassanzia/pen/zZvzRK)

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot of how it renders on my browser.

Comment: I tried the original code on liveweave and it does indeed change the position. It isn't the exact height amount, for some reason. http://liveweave.com/DHES1q I removed padding and moved the div to the right to see if the positioning is correct or not.

Comment: No. As the title suggests, I wanted to use percentages, not absolute values. I encountered the issue and posted the answer.

Comment: i see, i'm glad you have figured this out, :) .. i'm commenting this here as i can't comment on your answer, sometimes solution is just so obvious but our minds are so distracted or blurred that we can't see it..